# Initializing an sql query as a dataclass

Tags: python, sql, auto-generate, python-dataclasses

The goal is to achieve the selected columns in SQL based on the some manual classification of the fields, e.g.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Q:
    fruits = ('taste', 'color', 'shine')
    vege = ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable')
    meat = ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name')
    carbs = ('is_refined', 'gi')

    @static_method
    def get_fields(self, add_fruits=False, add_vege=False, add_meat=False, add_carbs=False):
         fields = set()
         fields.update(self.fruits) if add_fruits else None
         fields.update(self.vege) if add_vege else None
         fields.update(self.meat) if add_meat else None
         fields.update(self.carbs) if add_carbs else None
         return sorted(",".join(sorted(fields)))


print(f"SELECT {Q.get_fields(add_fruits=True, add_vege=True)} from food_features")
```

Given a large list of categories of fields in `Q` object, **how do we avoid the hardcoded in the `.get_fields` function?**

```
fields.update(self._field_name_) if add_field_name else None
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the output/functionality you're looking for?

```
class Q :
    def __init__(self):
        self.categories = {
            'fruits': ('taste', 'color', 'shine'),
            'vege': ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable'),
            'meat': ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name'),
            'carbs': ('is_refined', 'gi')
        }
    
    def get_fields(self, groups):
        fields = []
        for group in groups:
            fields.extend(self.categories[group])
        return", ".join(sorted(set(fields)))

value = Q()
print(f"SELECT {value.get_fields(['fruits', 'vege'])} FROM food_features")
```

Output:

```
SELECT color, is_green, juiceable, shine, taste FROM food_features
```

Comment: This might have the correct functionality, but does not use a dataclass as the question title indicates (the choice of a dataclass here may be arguable, but is separate matter).

Answer (score 1):

You may just use a `dict` for the categories, and a `set` comprehension:

```
>>> @dataclass
class Q:
    fields = {
              'fruits' : ('taste', 'color', 'shine'),
              'vege' : ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable'),
              'meat' : ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name'),
              'carbs' : ('is_refined', 'gi')
             }

    @staticmethod
    def get_fields(to_add):
        return ', '.join({f for x in to_add for f in Q.fields[x]})

print(f"SELECT {Q.get_fields(('fruits','vege'))} from food_features")

SELECT taste, juiceable, shine, color, is_green from food_features
```

Comment: This requires a minor rework of the original code, but I'd say it's definitely the best answer here - easy to read, and does the trick.

Comment: @optimus_prime what do u think about my improved solution ?

Comment: @PleSo it works....but is still to me ultimately a workaround to implementing a dictionary in the first place - the point here is that we have a key-value situation with the 'fruit'/'vege', etc., and their associated sets - so why reinvent the wheel? I'm guessing it will ultimately just cause you more time later when you come back to the code. Plus, the set comprehension here is quite elegant.

Comment: @optimus_prime thanks for the feedback. It is true, the dictionary solution is more easy to think about and implement. About reinventing the wheel, I wanted to give him a fully backwards compatible solution for his code, the thing with add_* prefix in arguments and the option to keep fields in the class, which imo is questionable in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [kwargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) and [__ getattribute __](https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6) method

**EDIT:**

A more readable & efficient approach:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import reduce

@dataclass
class Q:
    fruits = ('taste', 'color', 'shine')
    vege = ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable')
    meat = ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name')
    carbs = ('is_refined', 'gi')

    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls, **kwargs):
        fields = set()

        for key, is_key_true in kwargs.items():
          if is_key_true:
            fields.update(getattr(cls, key.replace('add_', '')))

        return ", ".join(sorted(fields))

print(f"SELECT {Q.get_fields(add_fruits=True, add_vege=True, add_meat=False)} from food_features")
```

This will output

```
SELECT color, is_green, juiceable, shine, taste from food_features
```

**Old code & some explains**:

Using kwargs you will receive a dictionary of function arguments, where you can put anything you want to add. For example `add_fruits=True, add_vege=True, etc`. We will use that dictionary to map the arguments in a tuple **(parameter, value)**, but removing the `add_` prefix. We add all of them to a list and you will end up having the values list of attributes and a boolean that tell us if we want to add them to our query or not. `[('fruits', True), ('vege', True)]`

We iterate in `values` list, and for every attribute that has `True` we get the data from the class attribute using `__getattribute__` method.

We will have a list of tuples of attributes, we just have to convert them to a list, in order to have all values that we want in a single list.

Now that we have the list of values, we just have to `join` the list with ", " to comma space them.

And.. that's it..

Check the code below.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Q:
    fruits = ('taste', 'color', 'shine')
    vege = ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable')
    meat = ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name')
    carbs = ('is_refined', 'gi')

    
    def get_fields(self, **kwargs):
        values = [(key.replace('add_', ''), value) for key, value in kwargs.items()]
        tuples_query = [self.__getattribute__(key) for key, value in values if value]
        query = [field for single_tuple in tuples_query for field in single_tuple]
        
        return ", ".join(query)

q = Q()

print(f"SELECT {q.get_fields(add_fruits=True, add_vege=True, add_meat=False)} from food_features")
```

This will output

```
SELECT taste, color, shine, is_green, color, juiceable from food_features
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest using an `Enum` to model the classification of fields or groups for the SQL query.

For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from typing import Sequence


@dataclass
class Q:

    class Group(Enum):
        FRUIT = ('taste', 'color', 'shine')
        VEG = ('is_green', 'color', 'juiceable')
        MEAT = ('is_white', 'is_dark', 'is_red', 'meat_name')
        CARBS = ('is_refined', 'gi')

    @staticmethod
    def get_fields(groups: Sequence['Q.Group'] = None):
        fields = set()

        if not groups:  # if no groups specified, just select everything
            return '*'

        for g in groups:
            fields.update(g.value)

        return ','.join(sorted(fields))

    @classmethod
    def get_query(cls, *groups: 'Q.Group'):
        return f'SELECT {cls.get_fields(groups)} from food_features'


print(Q.get_query())
print(Q.get_query(Q.Group.FRUIT, Q.Group.VEG))
```

Output:

```sql
SELECT * from food_features
SELECT color,is_green,juiceable,shine,taste from food_features
```